# Listing article updates on cv

Tags: publications, cv

What does the crowd think about how to list an article update on a cv?

For example, I have a peer-reviewed encyclopedia article that the publishers have asked me to update after 2 years. This updated article still has the same title (after all, it's the encyclopedia entry name) but content is approx. 25% different, and will be peer-reviewed.

What is the best way to indicate this new contribution on my cv?

BTW: I am, perhaps obviously by the question, early career.

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume that you already have listed in your CV the earlier article (the version 1) in the following way.

> Author Name, Title, Encyclopedia, Version **1**, Dated online: xx-xx-xxxx; WWW: website

Now, you could just replace the above with the following:

> Author Name, Title, Encyclopedia, Version **2**, Dated online: xx-xx-xxxx; WWW: website (Web version 1: website)

Though there is 25% difference, I would not go with redundant information in a CV.